# Problema ao emular app Android

Tags: android, eclipse, emulador

Meu eclipse teve uns problemas e eu reinstalei o eclipse e o sdk, mas ai quando vou emular o app aparece a seguinte mensagem no console:

> [2015-06-24 12:26:12 - SuperOffer] Android Launch!
>
> [2015-06-24 12:26:12 - SuperOffer] adb is running normally.
>
> [2015-06-24 12:26:12 - SuperOffer] No Launcher activity found!
>
> [2015-06-24 12:26:12 - SuperOffer] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
>
> [2015-06-24 12:26:12 - SuperOffer] Performing sync
>
> [2015-06-24 12:26:12 - SuperOffer] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
>
> [2015-06-24 12:26:12 - SuperOffer] \SuperOffer\bin\SuperOffer.apk installed on device
>
> [2015-06-24 12:26:12 - SuperOffer] Done!

Porém no `LogCat` exibe:

> 06-24 11:35:05.599: I/InputDispatcher(539): Dropping event because there is no touchable window at (924, 647).
>
> 06-24 11:35:05.643: D/MobileDataStateTracker(539): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
>
> 06-24 11:35:20.835: D/AndroidRuntime(1475): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
>
> 06-24 11:35:20.835: D/AndroidRuntime(1475): CheckJNI is OFF
>
> 06-24 11:35:20.843: D/dalvikvm(1475): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
>
> 06-24 11:35:20.843: D/dalvikvm(1475): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
>
> 06-24 11:35:20.847: D/dalvikvm(1475): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
>
> 06-24 11:35:20.847: D/dalvikvm(1475): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
>
> 06-24 11:35:20.847: D/dalvikvm(1475): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
>
> 06-24 11:35:20.875: D/dalvikvm(1475): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
>
> 06-24 11:35:20.939: E/memtrack(1475): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>
> 06-24 11:35:20.939: E/android.os.Debug(1475): failed to load memtrack module: -2
>
> 06-24 11:35:21.063: D/AndroidRuntime(1475): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
>
> 06-24 11:35:21.067: D/AndroidRuntime(1475): Shutting down VM
>
> 06-24 11:35:21.067: D/dalvikvm(1475): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
>
> 06-24 11:35:24.463: D/ConnectivityService(539): Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
>
> 06-24 11:35:24.463: D/ConnectivityService(539): Done.
> 06-24 11:35:24.467: D/ConnectivityService(539): Setting timer for 720seconds

Mas ele não roda e nem nada, sempre emulei pelo meu celular ou genymotion e sim, o eclipse esta reconhecendo ambos.

Agradeço a atenção de todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Diogo**, veja:

```
[2015-06-24 12:26:12 - SuperOffer] No Launcher activity found!
[2015-06-24 12:26:12 - SuperOffer] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

Seu arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml` não contém o indicador de launcher. Verifique se estão em  `<intent-filter>`:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Exemplo**

**`AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name="ExampleActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Obs**.: Não esqueça de alterar `ExampleActivity` pelo nome do seu Activity principal.

---

**Algo mais**

`06-24 11:35:20.939: E/memtrack(1475): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)`

Experimente com outros emuladores, e até mesmo em dispositivo real .. talvez o seu `"Couldn't load memtrack"` esteja relacionado a seu emulador. Tente alterá-la em "Run Configuration" e não se esqueça de alterar sua API nele também.

Comment: Ôô Felipe, perdão a demora e agradeço, era esse mesmo o problema!! Valeeeu!!

Comment: kkkk magina, não foi nada!